# Where to find sbtopts in Windows

Tags: scala, sbt

The path to sbtopts in my Linux system is:

```
/usr/local/etc/sbtopts
```

Where can I find this file in Windows (I am using sbt 0.13).

Answer (score 5):

If you used the [msi installer](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Installing-sbt-on-Windows.html) to install sbt in Windows, then the `sbtopts` file should be located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\conf` folder.